# How do I create a custom handler in torchserve?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchserve

I am trying to create a custom handler on Torchserve.
The custom handler has been modified as follows

```py
# custom handler file

# model_handler.py

"""
ModelHandler defines a custom model handler.
"""
import os
import soundfile
from espnet2.bin.enh_inference import *

from ts.torch_handler.base_handler import BaseHandler

class ModelHandler(BaseHandler):
    """
    A custom model handler implementation.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._context = None
        self.initialized = False
        self.model = None
        self.device = None

    def initialize(self, context):
        """
        Invoke by torchserve for loading a model
        :param context: context contains model server system properties
        :return:
        """

        #  load the model
        self.manifest = context.manifest

        properties = context.system_properties
        model_dir = properties.get("model_dir")
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:" + str(properties.get("gpu_id")) if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

        # Read model serialize/pt file
        serialized_file = self.manifest['model']['serializedFile']
        model_pt_path = os.path.join(model_dir, serialized_file)

        if not os.path.isfile(model_pt_path):
            raise RuntimeError("Missing the model.pt file")

        self.model = SeparateSpeech("train_enh_transformer_tf.yaml", "valid.loss.best.pth")

        self.initialized = True

    def preprocess(self,data):
        audio_data, rate  = soundfile.read(data)
        preprocessed_data = audio_data[np.newaxis, :]

        return preprocessed_data

    def inference(self, model_input):
        model_output = self.model(model_input)
        return model_output
    def postprocess(self, inference_output):
        """
        Return inference result.
        :param inference_output: list of inference output
        :return: list of predict results
        """
        # Take output from network and post-process to desired format
        postprocess_output = inference_output
        #wav ni suru
        return postprocess_output

    def handle(self, data, context):
        model_input = self.preprocess(data)
        model_output = self.inference(model_input)
        return self.postprocess(model_output)
```

The torchserve appears to be working.

The Torchserve logs are as follows

```
root@5c780ba74916:~/files# torchserve --start --ncs --model-store model_store --models denoise_transformer=denoise_transformer.mar
root@5c780ba74916:~/files# WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2022-08-24T14:06:06,662 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager - Initializing plugins manager...
2022-08-24T14:06:06,796 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer -
Torchserve version: 0.6.0
TS Home: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
Current directory: /root/files
Temp directory: /tmp
Number of GPUs: 1
Number of CPUs: 16
Max heap size: 4002 M
Python executable: /usr/bin/python3
Config file: N/A
Inference address: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Management address: http://127.0.0.1:8081
Metrics address: http://127.0.0.1:8082
Model Store: /root/files/model_store
Initial Models: denoise_transformer=denoise_transformer.mar
Log dir: /root/files/logs
Metrics dir: /root/files/logs
Netty threads: 0
Netty client threads: 0
Default workers per model: 1
Blacklist Regex: N/A
Maximum Response Size: 6553500
Maximum Request Size: 6553500
Limit Maximum Image Pixels: true
Prefer direct buffer: false
Allowed Urls: [file://.*|http(s)?://.*]
Custom python dependency for model allowed: false
Metrics report format: prometheus
Enable metrics API: true
Workflow Store: /root/files/model_store
Model config: N/A
2022-08-24T14:06:06,805 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager -  Loading snapshot serializer plugin...
2022-08-24T14:06:06,817 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Loading initial models: denoise_transformer.mar
2022-08-24T14:06:07,006 [DEBUG] main org.pytorch.serve.wlm.ModelVersionedRefs - Adding new version 1.0 for model denoise_transformer
2022-08-24T14:06:07,007 [DEBUG] main org.pytorch.serve.wlm.ModelVersionedRefs - Setting default version to 1.0 for model denoise_transformer
2022-08-24T14:06:07,007 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.wlm.ModelManager - Model denoise_transformer loaded.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,007 [DEBUG] main org.pytorch.serve.wlm.ModelManager - updateModel: denoise_transformer, count: 1
2022-08-24T14:06:07,015 [DEBUG] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Worker cmdline: [/usr/bin/python3, /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ts/model_service_worker.py, --sock-type, unix, --sock-name, /tmp/.ts.sock.9000]
2022-08-24T14:06:07,016 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Initialize Inference server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,059 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Inference API bind to: http://127.0.0.1:8080
2022-08-24T14:06:07,059 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Initialize Management server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,060 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Management API bind to: http://127.0.0.1:8081
2022-08-24T14:06:07,060 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Initialize Metrics server with: EpollServerSocketChannel.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,062 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer - Metrics API bind to: http://127.0.0.1:8082
Model server started.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,258 [WARN ] pool-3-thread-1 org.pytorch.serve.metrics.MetricCollector - worker pid is not available yet.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,363 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Listening on port: /tmp/.ts.sock.9000
2022-08-24T14:06:07,364 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - [PID]6258
2022-08-24T14:06:07,364 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Torch worker started.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,365 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Python runtime: 3.8.10
2022-08-24T14:06:07,365 [DEBUG] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 State change null -> WORKER_STARTED
2022-08-24T14:06:07,368 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Connecting to: /tmp/.ts.sock.9000
2022-08-24T14:06:07,374 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Connection accepted: /tmp/.ts.sock.9000.
2022-08-24T14:06:07,376 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Flushing req. to backend at: 1661317567376
2022-08-24T14:06:07,398 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - model_name: denoise_transformer, batchSize: 1
2022-08-24T14:06:07,596 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - CPUUtilization.Percent:0.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,596 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskAvailable.Gigabytes:220.49971389770508|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,597 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskUsage.Gigabytes:17.66714859008789|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,597 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - DiskUtilization.Percent:7.4|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,597 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - GPUMemoryUtilization.Percent:17.9931640625|#Level:Host,device_id:0|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,597 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - GPUMemoryUsed.Megabytes:1474|#Level:Host,device_id:0|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,598 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - GPUUtilization.Percent:8|#Level:Host,device_id:0|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,598 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryAvailable.Megabytes:14307.53515625|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,598 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryUsed.Megabytes:1372.1640625|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:07,598 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 TS_METRICS - MemoryUtilization.Percent:10.6|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317567
2022-08-24T14:06:08,306 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - encoder self-attention layer type = self-attention
2022-08-24T14:06:08,328 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Eps is deprecated in si_snr loss, set clamp_db instead.
2022-08-24T14:06:08,373 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Perform direct speech enhancement on the input
2022-08-24T14:06:08,390 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 992
2022-08-24T14:06:08,391 [DEBUG] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 State change WORKER_STARTED -> WORKER_MODEL_LOADED
2022-08-24T14:06:08,391 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 TS_METRICS - W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0.ms:1380|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317568
2022-08-24T14:06:08,391 [INFO ] W-9000-denoise_transformer_1.0 TS_METRICS - WorkerThreadTime.ms:23|#Level:Host|#hostname:5c780ba74916,timestamp:1661317568
```

I sent the wav file to torchserve with the following command

> curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/denoise_transformer -T Mix.wav

However, the following error was returned

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Request Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Request Error (invalid_request)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your request could not be processed. Request could not be handled
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
This could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed request.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Is there somewhere wrong?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here's an example but it seems the problem should be how you receive parse the data

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
from io import BytesIO
from ts.torch_handler.base_handler import BaseHandler

import torch
from model import Model

class SoundModelHandler(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SoundModelHandler, self).__init__()
        self.initialized = False

    def preproc_one_wav(self, req: Dict[str, bytearray]) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, int]:
        """
        Function to convert req data to image
        :param req:
        :return: np array of wav form
        """
        wav_byte = req.get("data")
        
        if wav_byte is None:
            wav_byte = req.get('body')
        
        # create a stream from the encoded image
        wav, sr = sf.read(BytesIO(wav_byte))
        return wav, sr
        
    def initialize(self, context):
        """
        Invoke by torchserve for loading a model
        :param context: context contains model server system properties
        :return:
        """
        self.manifest = context.manifest
        
        properties = context.system_properties
        model_dir = properties.get("model_dir")
        self._context = context

        self.model = Model()
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_dir + 'weights.pt'))
        
        self.initialize = True
        self.device = torch.device(
            "cuda:" + str(properties.get("gpu_id"))
            if torch.cuda.is_available() and properties.get("gpu_id") is not None
            else "cpu"
        )

        
    def preprocess(self, requests: List[Dict[str, bytearray]]):
        """
        Function to prepare data from the model
        
        :param requests:
        :return: tensor of the processed shape specified by the model
        """
        batch_crop = [self.preproc_one_wav(req) for req in requests]

        # Do something here if you want return as torch tensor
        # You can apply torch cat here as well
        batch = torch.cat(batch_crop)
        
        return batch
        
    def inference(self, model_input: torch.Tensor):
        """
        Given the data from .preprocess, perform inference using the model.
        
        :param reqeuest:
        :return: Logits or predictions given by the model
        """
        with torch.no_grad():
            generated_ids = self.model.generate(model_input.to(self.device))
        
        return generated_ids
```

Btw heres an example you can do to make a request to your model in python

```py
import json
import requests

sample = {'data': wav_in_byte}
results = requests.post('ip:port', data=json.dumps(sample))
# parse results
get_results = results.json()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
Your sample code does not inherit from BaseHandler, is that OK?

Comment: Hi you can just plug in to the basehandler, for simplicity sake i did as such but let me fix that, btw its meant to be in the base handler, the preprocess is an overwrriten method

Comment: I fixed it but please make adjustments as you see fit, but the main part to you need to focus on is the preprocess func

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Do you mean that I can input/output the wav file by sending the curl command as follows using the method you introduced?

Comment: > curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/denoise_transformer -T Mix.wav